# How to set title of x-axis and y-axis name for amChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

In amChart how can I set a custom name (string) for the X axis and Y axis titles of a chart?

(Horizontal Axis and Vertical Axis)

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
  "graphs": [ {
    /*"bullet": "circle",
    "bulletSize": 8,*/
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
  } ],
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`title`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#title) parameters for each of the axis. You will need to add [`valueAxes`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmXYChart#valueAxes) definitions, to the chart config, though. Even if they will contain only `title` parameter.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
  "graphs": [ {
    /*"bullet": "circle",
    "bulletSize": 8,*/
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "xField": "x",
    "yField": "y",
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Y axis"
  }, {
    "position": "bottom",
    "title": "X axis"
  } ]
} );
```